# Comparing images: Don't take image I write

Tags: python, image, compare

I have a problem with my code. The code works perfect when it starts looping, but after a number of loops it stops reading new screenshots and just reads the previous made ones.

```
loop 1: image 2c: result 2c
loop 2: image Qd: result Qd
...
loop 10: image Td: result Td
loop 11: image As: result Td
loop 12: image 3s: result Td
```

I tried to use `time.sleep()` and delete the image after reading it but that didn't fix the problem so I have no idea why code doesn't use new screenshots.

When I run the same code on those screenshots without loops I always get the correct result, so why is the loop misbehaving?

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from itertools import izip
from PIL import Image
import time

symbolslist =     ["2c","3c","4c","5c","6c","7c","8c","9c","Tc","Jc","Qc","Kc","Ac","2h","3h","4h","5h","6h","7h","8h","9h","Th","Jh","Qh","Kh","Ah","2d","3d","4d","5d","6d","7d","8d","9d","Td","Jd","Qd","Kd","Ad","2s","3s","4s","5s","6s","7s","8s","9s","Ts","Js","Qs","Ks","As"]
varc1 = 1
vardiffc1 = 1
varc2 = 1
vardiffc2 = 1

onoff=1
while onoff < 2:
c=0
while c<len(symbolslist):
     #Screenshot and save

    imc1=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(367,277,383,312)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2 21 24
    imc1.save("c1.png","png")
    time.sleep(0.6)

    i1 = Image.open("c1.png")
    i2 = Image.open("images/c1/" +symbolslist[c] +".png")
    assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
    assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."

    pairs = izip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
    if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
    # for gray-scale jpegs
        dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
    else:
        dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))

    ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
    diff = (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents
    #print "Difference (percentage):", (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents
    #print diff

    if diff <= vardiffc1:
        #print diff
        #print vardiff
       varc1 = symbolslist[c]
        vardiffc1 = diff
        if diff <= 0.5:
            c=len(symbolslist)
        else:
             pass
    else:
        pass


    c+=1

print varc1
```

Comment: To clarify, is the issue just that it's giving the wrong names for the images or is there more? Also can you add `print c` at the start of the loop to make sure it's actually getting incremented properly.

Comment: I think I fixed, the problem is with vardiffc1, I need put vardiffc1 = 1 inside loop because if find a image diff = 0.02 set vardiffc1 = 0.02 and in the next loop find image diff 0.03 can not set new symbolist value because vardiffc1 = 0.02

Comment: Glad you found a solution! If it's definitely working for you, you can add it as an answer to your own question, for the benefit of anyone else who has this issue and finds your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I lose many time try to fix and your idea make me find solution. I want give you reputation but I not see how, I'm new here.

Comment: No problem, glad I helped! One note about how Stack Overflow works. Please don't edit your original question to contain the working code once the problem is solved, it may be confusing to people when they see it already contains the solution. Having the correct code in the answer is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed, the problem is with vardiffc1, I need put vardiffc1 = 1 inside loop because if find a image diff = 0.02 set vardiffc1 = 0.02 and in the next loop if find image diff 0.03 can not set new symbolist value because vardiffc1 = 0.02

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from itertools import izip
from PIL import Image
import time

symbolslist =     ["2c","3c","4c","5c","6c","7c","8c","9c","Tc","Jc","Qc","Kc","Ac","2h","3h","4h","5h","6h","7h","8h","9h","Th","Jh","Qh","Kh","Ah","2d","3d","4d","5d","6d","7d","8d","9d","Td","Jd","Qd","Kd","Ad","2s","3s","4s","5s","6s","7s","8s","9s","Ts","Js","Qs","Ks","As"]


onoff=1
while onoff < 2:
c=0
while c<len(symbolslist):
varc1 = 1
vardiffc1 = 1
varc2 = 1
vardiffc2 = 1
#Screenshot and save

imc1=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(367,277,383,312)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2 21 24
imc1.save("c1.png","png")
time.sleep(0.6)

i1 = Image.open("c1.png")
i2 = Image.open("images/c1/" +symbolslist[c] +".png")
assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."

pairs = izip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
# for gray-scale jpegs
    dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
else:
    dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))

ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
diff = (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents
#print "Difference (percentage):", (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents
#print diff

if diff <= vardiffc1:
    #print diff
    #print vardiff
   varc1 = symbolslist[c]
    vardiffc1 = diff
    if diff <= 0.5:
        c=len(symbolslist)
    else:
         pass
else:
    pass


c+=1

print varc1
```